# Bootstrap Columns not stacking right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have many blocks/portlets of different heights on my page, and I would like them to stack nicely and fit into white space with no gaps. http://www.bootply.com/pYK3fLTn7c In the following example, Block 4 should be under Block 1, and even in the place it's in (under Block 2) shouldn't it fit into the white space? Pinterest has a nice example of this (or http://jsfiddle.net/M34e2/ but my widths may differ). Or can we do this without adding plugins (I already have sortable working)? http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Responsive-Fluid-Drag-and-Drop-Grid-Layout-with-jQuery-gridstack-js/ Thanks for any help in advance.

```
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="col-lg-4" style="height: 200px; border: 1px #ccc solid">
    <h1>Block 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4" style="height: 100px; border: 1px #ff0 solid">
    <h1>Block 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4" style="height: 150px; border: 1px #f00 solid">
    <h1>Block 3</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4" style="height: 175px; border: 1px green solid">
    <h1>Block 4</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4" style="height: 175px; border: 1px blue solid">
    <h1>Block 5</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4" style="height: 75px; border: 1px pink solid">
    <h1>Block 6</h1>
  </div>

</div><!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: This isn't feasible in a vertical-column grid. You could use something like Masonry, but the key is to have all elements the same height and use rows rather than columns.

Answer (score 2):

To ensure block 4 is under 1, you would need to use a row:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class='row'>
    <div class="col-lg-4" style="height: 200px; border: 1px #ccc solid">
      <h1>Block 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4" style="height: 100px; border: 1px #ff0 solid">
      <h1>Block 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4" style="height: 150px; border: 1px #f00 solid">
      <h1>Block 3</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class="col-lg-4" style="height: 175px; border: 1px green solid">
      <h1>Block 4</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4" style="height: 175px; border: 1px blue solid">
      <h1>Block 5</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4" style="height: 75px; border: 1px pink solid">
      <h1>Block 6</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/xWzvbdxvvi#

And note, just to ensure you know the -lg classes only works at higher resolution.  On smaller screens it will stack one on to of the other (block 2 is under block 1) for -md, -sm, and -xs sized screens.

[UPDATE: 2015-03-18 per comments]
If all you want to do is have them stack vertically without space, the only other option is this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-lg-4'>
      <div style="height: 200px; border: 1px #ccc solid">
        <h1>Block 1</h1>
      </div>
      <div style="height: 175px; border: 1px green solid">
        <h1>Block 4</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-lg-4'>
      <div style="height: 100px; border: 1px #ff0 solid">
        <h1>Block 2</h1>
      </div>
      <div style="height: 175px; border: 1px blue solid">
        <h1>Block 5</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div style="height: 150px; border: 1px #f00 solid">
        <h1>Block 3</h1>
      </div>
      <div style="height: 75px; border: 1px pink solid">
        <h1>Block 6</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is going to stack vertically within the same column, but this limits you in completely different ways.

Bootstrap is about manually configuring your grid to the display you want for each viewing size...it is NOT something that's going to dynamically try to puzzle-piece your sections together like a newspaper as the link you provided seems to do.

Comment: This does not solve my issue. There is white space between block 2 and 5, and block 3 and 6.

Comment: Also, clear left avoids adding the row classes. I want to avoid adding rows, because these blocks have drag and drop capabilities.

Comment: @triplethreat77 there is whitespace because you have different heights set for all the boxes. How could there not be whitespace? What are you expecting the boxes to look like? Bootstrap is supposed to be used with `row`s and omitting them is just going to cause layout problems.

Comment: @CodingWithSpike This is what I'd like to accomplish. http://www.inwebson.com/demo/blocksit-js/demo1/

Comment: @triplethreat77, updated but, I'm sure, not to your liking.  Not sure what you would need to use to get your desired result other than a javascript framework.

Answer (score -1):

The link example you gave changes layout on refresh and uses js. If using bootstrap, not adding rows you will yield a less predictable layout, if using a 12 column bootstrap grid, any cols added up over 12 wrap to the next row. -lg class is for desktop/higher resolution. You can add multiple classes to each div for handling smaller resolutions.